# "pointer being freed was not allocated" while using memcpy

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I trying to use memcpy to copy content from one array to another, the code is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int *a;
    a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    a[0] = 4;
    a[1] = 3;
    a[2] = 2;
    a[3] = 1;

    int *b;
    b = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(a));

    free(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("b[%d]:%d",i,b[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(b));
    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to run it, I encounter the following error:

```
b[0]:4b[1]:3b[2]:2b[3]:18
mem(6131,0x7fffbb4723c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fa5a4c02890: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

This error disappear if I remove the `free(b)` piece of code, however, I don't know why since I explicitly allocate resource to it.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: You need to take the time to appreciate the difference between a pointer and a pointee. What holds and address, and what is at that address.

Comment: `memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(a));` overwrites address in b with address in a, so b is the same after that, this is why `free(a)` also frees `b`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `memcpy` is wrong. You're copying the value of the pointer `a` into `b` instead of copying the data pointed by `a` into the buffer pointed by `b`. You end up doing a double free because `a` and `b` point to the same place. Replace your `memcpy` call with this:

```
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(int)*4);
```

Comment: @JeremyP That was thought went behind (currently removed) comments.

Answer (score 5):

```
memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(a));
```

This doesn't copy the 4 ints that `a` points at to the 4 ints that `b` points at.

This instead overwrites `b` with the contents of `a`. Then you end up doing a double free, since both `a` and `b` contain the same address.

I'll repeat my comment on your question: You need to take the time to appreciate the difference between a pointer and a pointee. What holds and address, and what is at that address.

Comment: I don't think there's any memory trashing going on with the `memcpy`. `sizeof(a)` is the size of `int*`.

Comment: @Kevin - Now that I had the time to rethink the nonsense I wrote, all I can say is thanks for pointing it out. I guess I should follow my own advise to the OP :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the exact problem why we say  [not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

First things first, you are missing `stdlib.h` include and because of that, the prototype of `malloc()` is not known and your compiler *assumnes* that it returns an `int`. This creates the mismatch between the implicit declaration and the actual definition, which at a later stage, invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, another major issue is when you write `memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(a));` which is very wrong. You want to supply `a` and `b` themselves, as you want to copy the contents of the memory location pointed by `a` to the memory location pointed by `b`, not the address of the pointers.

In your case, the erroneous call actually *messes up* the contents of `b`, i.e., the actual pointer returned by `malloc()`. Therefore, as we know, passing a pointer which was not exactly returned by memory allocator functions or already `free()`-d, to `free()` causes UB, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3,

> [...] Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined.

you're getting into trouble, as the current pointer held by `b` is the same one as `a` which has been already passed to `free()`. As mentioned in the other answer(s) <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42653772/2173917)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42653761/2173917)</sup>, you need to write

```
 memcpy(b, a, sizeof(int)*4);
```

***Moral of the story:*** Enable compiler warnings and always check the data types.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you free b when you do free(a). Because the memory zone is the same after doing memcpy. Try to do free(b) at the end, without the free(a).